# SharePoint Web-services disabling automatically causing site down

Tags: web-services, security, central-administration, password

SharePoint search host controller and SharePoint Server Search 15 disabling every time I enable it. Reason I found that recently I have changed service account password which is used for those two services.

I do not know where all I should update this changed password.
I tried to change the password in the central admin under Manage service accounts. but once I select my account and try to change password- upon clicking ok button its giving error as

> The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted

ULS logs also saying same. Below is ULS recorded error.

> "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted at Microsoft.SharePoint.Win32.SPNetApi32.NetUserChangePassword(String loginName, SecureString oldPassword, SecureString password) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPManagedAccount.AttemptPasswordChange(SecureString possibleCurrentPassword, SecureString newPassword) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPManagedAccount.ChangePassword(SecureString newPassword, EventProcessingOptions eventFlags) at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ManageAccountPage.BtnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs args) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.PageProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)"

How to use `Set-SPManagedAccount` command to change the password ?

Error:-
[image]

Comment: Couple of things: are you using the $ in your service accounts? is their any invalid / deleted account still exist in the managed account page?

Answer (score 0):

Password must be changed:

- in Central Administration > Security > Configure managed accounts - click EDIT on account and Change password now
- Try start Search Service, if it fails :

Check Windows Services and accounts here (update account with new password)

- SharePoint Search Host Controller
- SharePoint Server Search 15

If it fails again, look in IIS Web Service for account which are used on Search App Pool, update too.

If you want to use Set-SPManagedAccount:

```
$acc = Get-SPManagedAccount -Identity "domain\login"
Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $acc -NewPassword "password"
```

[image]

[image]

I tried what you said but giving me the error.
[image]

Comment: yeah i tried what you have mentioned from central admin and from shell command as well . But above mentioned error is coming "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted"

Comment: I added the powershell for changing password, otherwise, has your domain the same FQDN as short name? Something like : microsoft.com and MS\ ?
or you can try add another account into Managed accounts if this works.

Comment: "No matching account found " error in SP PowerShell. used your command and this also same error. Set-SPManagedAccount -identity "AUTH\$account001" -NewPassword (ConvertTo-Securestring "abc.for-15" -AsPlainText -Force) -SetNewPassword

Comment: you must firstly Get-SPManagedAccount and after this Set-SPManagedAccount.
You have $ in account? Thats strange.
Try add new account via Central Administration

Comment: i used Get-SPManagedAccount and got list of service accounts which has my required account too. If i try to add account its saying account exists.

Comment: ok so - this is our dev environment here is exactly what you need to do:
List all accounts :
* Get-SPManagedAccount
* $acc = Get-SPManagedAccounts - Identity "DEV\vinduska"
* Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $acc -NewPassword (ConvertTo-Securestring "Heslo.123" -AsPlainText -Force)
* Confirm Password: Type the same
* Write Y and ENTER
* Done

Comment: Added screenshots into my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82832/discussion-between-chetan-and-zdenk-vinduska).

Comment: i have added screenshots, I did exactly what you said. Still same error

Comment: I really dont know why you have problem with these powershells cmdlts.

Comment: AUTH is your domain? Have you resolved this problem?